# How to Perform a button click in Protractor

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor

I need to click on the Ok button on a popup that has this HTML rendering:

```
<div class="ui-dialog-buttonpane ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix">
  <div class="ui-dialog-buttonset">
    <button type="button">Ok</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've tried finding its XPATH and CSS and it does not seem to click it.
How do I click on this OK button?

Comment: is the button appearing onscreen?

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
element(by.css(.ui-dialog-buttonset)).then(function(ok){
  ok.element(by.buttonText(ok)).click();
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Is the dialog visible to check?:

```
ptor.wait(function(){
  return ptor.isElementPresent(by.css('.ui-dialog-buttonpane');
},5000,'wait for dialog');
```

If so:

```
element(by.tagName('button')).click();
```

Answer (score -2):

These 2 approaches did not work:

Via CSS: ('css', '[type="button"]'); // Does not work

Via x-path: ('xpath', '/html/body/div[4]/div[3]/div/button');

Finally, found that when I pass xpath as follows, it works:
('xpath', "//button[text() = 'Ok']");

Answer (score -2):

Please try the below methods
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.sendKeys(Keys.TAB,Keys.Return).build().perform();

Please check when OK button focus by using TAB keys. If its once then above method works else you can add multiple TAB keys like sendKeys(Keys.TAB,Keys.TAB,Keys.Return)